# Networking layer module

Tags: java, object-oriented, design-patterns

These two classes are part of a networking layer module that I am building:

```
public abstract class BaseRequest {

    protected RequestCreator mCreator;

    public BaseRequest() {
        setupRequestCreator();
    }

    private setupRequestCreator() {
        mCreator = new RequestCreator.Builder()
            .headers(getHeaders())
            .parser(getParser())
            .build();
    }

    public abstract Headers getHeaders();
    public abstract Parser getParser();
}

public class UserRequest extends BaseRequest {

    private Headers mHeaders;
    private Request<User> mRequest;

    private interface UserService {
        @GET("/users/{id}")
        User getUser(String id);
    }

    public UserRequest(Headers headers) {
        mHeaders = headers;
        mRequest = mCreator.createRequest(UserService.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Headers getHeaders() {
        return mHeaders;
    }

    @Override
    public Parser getParser() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The framework that I am using requires me to configure/build a `RequestCreator` for each type of Request that I am going to use.

To make the process of adding new classes for different requests as pain-free as possible, I moved the building logic of the `RequestCreator` in an abstract class. This way I'll only have to extend it and override some methods that indicate how the `RequestCreator` should be configured - sort of a template method pattern.

The actual problem is this: when someone creates an instance of `UserRequest`, `super()` gets called right before `UserRequest`'s member variables are set. What this means is that the `RequestCreator` will already be built by the time `mHeaders` are set. This is wrong because the building process needs a reference to `mHeaders` in order for it to behave as intended.

One way to get around this is to leave `BaseRequest`'s constructor empty and to call `setupRequestCreator()` in the `UserRequest`'s constructor, but only after setting the instance variables first. This however feels "hacky" because other people will have to be aware of this when they are creating new subclasses.

I tried other workarounds too, but nothing felt quite right. I was hoping someone could provide me with a better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you using an abstract class in the first place?

I more think you should use a **factory method**. You could store the headers and the parser in a class, but make it an immutable class.

Another note, or maybe just my personal opinion: It is to my knowledge **not** a Java convention to prefix all member fields with `m`.

The only really valuable code that you have is this:

```
mCreator = new RequestCreator.Builder()
    .headers(getHeaders())
    .parser(getParser())
    .build();
```

and

```
mRequest = mCreator.createRequest(UserService.class);
```

So let's make factory methods!

```
public class Requests {

    public static RequestCreator newCreator(Headers headers, Parser parser) {
        mCreator = new RequestCreator.Builder()
            .headers(headers)
            .parser(parser)
            .build();
    }
}

public class UserRequest {

    private interface UserService {
        @GET("/users/{id}")
        User getUser(String id);
    }

    public static Request<User> createUserRequest(Headers headers) {
        return Requests.newCreator(headers, null).createRequest(UserService.class);
    }

}
```

Problem solved(?)

Comment: Thank you Simon! Prefixing member fields with **m** is not indeed a Java convention but this code is part of an Android app and this is a very common practice in Android. Google uses this convention it in their own Android classes and I guess other developers just stick with it. Your approach using factory methods is also a lot more flexible and it suits my problem quite well!